# zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client

Tags: java, apache, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I have installed IntelliJ Community 2018.1 on Windows 7 Professional. Running Java 1.8.0.172 jdk.

I am running Apache Storm related Simple Java code from Edureka Tutorials.

Very simple and basic. Just emit few integers from a spout and the bolt just doubles up each number and re-emits.

I am not running any local or remote zk/storm cluster. I am relying on the ZK/Storm instances that the code somehow generates itself. I do not have any Storm directory locally. All I have is IntelliJ and few dependency lines in pom.xml.

This is what I have in my Windows hosts file.

```
localhost sandbox.hortonworks.com sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com sandbox-hdf.hortonworks.com
127.0.0.1 sandbox.hortonworks.com sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com sandbox-hdf.hortonworks.com
```

When I run the Java program, I am consistently getting this error :-

```
org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x164ebfb3e3e000f, likely client has closed socket
```

Here are the steps I did to write my code :-

(1) Create new Maven project in IntelliJ.

(2) Add dependencies section to POM.xml so that storm-core libraries are imported. All validates fine.

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

(4) Create a Java class for Spout in IntelliJ.

```
import org.apache.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Values;

import java.util.Map;

public class IntegerSpout extends BaseRichSpout {

SpoutOutputCollector myspoutOutputCollector;
private Integer index = 2;

public void open(Map map, TopologyContext topologyContext, SpoutOutputCollector spoutOutputCollector) {
    this.myspoutOutputCollector = spoutOutputCollector;
        }

public void nextTuple() {
    //Emit 100 numbers from the Spout.
    if (index <100) {
        System.out.println("Index is " + Integer.toString(index));
        this.myspoutOutputCollector.emit(new Values(index));
        index++;
    }
}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
    outputFieldsDeclarer.declare(new Fields("field"));
}
```

}

(5) Feed these numbers from the Spout into a (Multiplier?) Bolt, that doubles each number from the spout and emits out further. Simple and Straightforward.

```
import org.apache.storm.topology.BasicOutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseBasicBolt;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Values;

public class MultiplierBolt extends BaseBasicBolt {
public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector basicOutputCollector) {
    Integer number = tuple.getInteger(0);
    number*= 2;
    basicOutputCollector.emit(new Values(number));
}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
    outputFieldsDeclarer.declare(new Fields("field"));
}
```

}

(6) Now write a Main class with a main() that defines a topology and connects the spout to the bolt and then submits it for execution.

```
import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;

public class MainTopology {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("IntegerSpout", new IntegerSpout());
    builder.setBolt("MultiplierBolt", new MultiplierBolt()).shuffleGrouping("IntegerSpout");

    Config config = new Config();
    config.setDebug(true);

    LocalCluster localCluster = new LocalCluster();

    try {
        localCluster.submitTopology("HelloTopology", config, builder.createTopology());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Raised");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        localCluster.shutdown();
    };
}
```

}

That's it folks. Now just compile them and run. I get mostly exceptions and errors in my log.

```
[NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - caught end of stream exception org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x164ebf470410009, likely client has closed socket
```

Any pointers of help will be appreciated.

TIA.

Amit

Comment: I wanted to put the complete log in here but the site prohibits me stating it is too long. Only 30000 chars allowed. My log has about a hundred thousand. Not sure how I could provide a hyperlink to it.

Comment: Is there a way to attach the zipped logs?

Comment: I don't know if you can attach files here, but you could always upload the log to a file sharing site and link it here.